# Colocar link activo com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho um código em javascript, visivel neste link 
http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1272/

Estou a tentar colocar os 3 primeiros links activos em simultaneo, se alguem clicar no "About MHG" ou "Workout Programs" ou "Fitness Tips", ou seja, clicar em 1 dos 3, ambos ficam activo.

Os restante, estão correctos, mas os 3 primeiros pretendia que ficassem activos em simultaneo.
é possivel?

```
    <ul class="navi">
        <li><a class="menu2" href="#">About MHG</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu3" href="#">Workout Programs</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu4" href="#">Fitness Tips</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu5" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
        <li><a class="menu6" href="#">Read Our Blog</a></li>
      </ul>


$('ul.navi').each(function(){
        // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
        // which tab is active and it's associated content
        var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

        // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
        // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
        $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content = $($active.attr('href'));

        // Hide the remaining content
        $links.not($active).each(function () {
            $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
        });

        // Bind the click event handler

        $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
            // Make the old tab inactive.
            $active.removeClass('active');
            $content.hide();

            // Update the variables with the new link and content
            $active = $(this);
            $content = $($(this).attr('href'));


            // Make the tab active.
            $active.addClass('active');

            $content.show();

            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });



    });
```

Comment: É isto que procura? http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1282/

Comment: Obrigado sergio! O problema ficou resolvido com a tua ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro deste event handler: `$(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){` pode fazer uma busca para saber qual o index desta ancora (na verdade do `li` pai).

Se souber isso pode saber se é um dessas 3 primeiras ancoras que recebeu o click. Este passo pode ser feito com:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').index() < 3) // fazer o que procura
```

Quando esta condição se verificar precisa de percorrer esses elementos e dar-lhes a classe que quer. Sugestão, para usar quando a condiçõ em cima fôr verdade:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li a').each(function(i){
      if (i<3)$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Os passos que este codigo dá são: parte da ancora clicada > sobe ao antecessor `ul` > procura as ancoras descendentes de elementos `li` > percorre uma a uma > atribui a classe às ancoras cujo index da seleção feita é inferior a 3. Ora como no javascript as arrays começam com index zero, a classe é adicionada aos indexs 0, 1 e 2.

Para adaptar o seu jsFiddle mudei `$active.removeClass('active');` para `$links.removeClass('active');` pois assim tira a classe de todos os links e não só do ultimo clicado.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1282/

Links sobre alguns métodos usados:

- [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) - retorna o index relativo aos elementos da coleção
- [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - retorna o primeiro ancestral que faz match com o seletor
- [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - retorna os elementos descendentes que fazem match com o seletor
- [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - percorre todos os elementos da coleção passando o index como primeiro argumento

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, tal como indicado ajudaste me a resolver o problema!

Comment: Apenas uma duvida adicional, ja consegui fazer com que ao entrar na pagina tambem se matenha activo os 3 primeiros. Mas pretendia mostrar o conteudo associado (que so funciona ao clicar sobre eles com o href="#tab58") é possivel mostrar mal entrar na pagina?

Comment: @user3644929, pode fazer assim antes do event handler: `$links.closest('ul').find('li a').each(function(i){ if (i<3)$(this).addClass('active');});` mas começo a achar que o seu código podia ser melhorado (simplificado) para isto: __http://jsfiddle.net/A888R/__ e aí só precisa ter no HTML a classe nas três primeiras ancoras.

Comment: DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1284/
A ideia é adicionar texto, isto será para implementar a legenda de um mapa, que ao entrar na pagina, ficará logo activo as 3 primeiras, com texto igual

Comment: @user3644929 tinha um bug no comentário em cima, corrigí. http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1285/ - mas dê uma olhada a esta versão simplificada: http://jsfiddle.net/A888R/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1284/
Obrigado pela ajuda, mas eu não posso excluir o restante codigo pois estou a usar textos. P.f verifica o DEMO

Comment: @user3644929 ok, estou a perceber: http://jsfiddle.net/9nd4j/1286/

Comment: funcionou! 5*
Muito Obrigado! E desculpe o trabalho dado